Where to find Auth and Token URLs of an OIDC authorization server?
I have an API which uses a AWS Cognito User Pool connected to Google for authentication and authorization within a Spring Boot application.
I am trying to interact with the Spring Boot application via the Thunder Client VSCode extension.  In the request, under the Auth tab, I've selected OAuth2, and I'm trying to get it to generate a token.
It's asking me for Auth URL and Token URL.
Where would I find these values?

OAuth2 endpoints of an OIDC authorization server are exposed in its OpenID configurations which should be available from {Issuer-URI}/.well-known/openid-configuration.
In the case of Amazon Cognito, the issuer URI should look something like https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{instance-id}

Thanks, I knew that but had forgotten :-)
